# changing wix templates to RTL

Tags: right-to-left, hebrew, velo

Can the Wix templates in https://www.wix.com/website/templates/ be changes to an RTL aligned template for a language such as Hebrew or Arabic?

I mean to ask if it can be done in a simple way such as changing a small number of configurations, and not going over manually over each an every text box and changing the text alignment.

Comment: I found these three links for your question, I hope they can help you as well. 
https://support.wix.com/en/article/languages-available-in-the-wix-editor-9444736 , https://support.wix.com/en/article/changing-the-direction-of-menu-tabs , https://support.wix.com/en/article/changing-the-text-direction

Comment: Thanks, but this method is on the level of the individual element, menu or text box. I was looking for something that would convert the direction all the elements on a site from LTR to RTL or vice versa.